# Mysql contar registros en subconsulta de select

Tags: mysql, select

Quisiera contar registros en una subconsulta:

Tengo por ejemplo una tabla con un id que quiero contar las veces que se repite:

select id, nombre, ventas, (select count(id) from nombre_tabla where pago='ok') as anteriores from nombre_tabla where pago='ok'

Lo que necesito es aparte de id, nombre, ventas un campo anteriores donde salga cuantas veces se repite ese id que estoy consultando. Parece simple pero, el asunto es que trae en cada registro el numero total de id en la tabla, claro... intenté poner un alias a la tabla de la subconsulta (a pesar que siempre es la misma tabla) y poner en el where de la subconsulta un alias.id=id pero tampoco me funciona, ya que lo que tengo que comparar es cuando sale el propio id de la consulta en la propia tabla!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para contar la cantidad de registros que se repiten en la tabla tendrías que usar la función COUNT(*) junto con la función GROUP BY.

En tu caso deberias usarla de la siguiente manera

```
select id, nombre, ventas, Count(*) as anteriores from nombre_tabla where pago='ok' GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

La función "count()" cuenta la cantidad de registros de una tabla, incluyendo los que tienen valor nulo. Para saber la cantidad de libros de la editorial "Planeta" tipeamos:

```
select count(*) from libros
  where editorial='Planeta';
```

En tu caso creo que debes conocer el valor del id, así lo buscas solo por ese valor y te debería regresar los que encuentre solo con el valor de ese id.

```
select "todos los campos que ocupes" count(id) from "tu tabla" where id='valor';
```

Saludos

Comment: El valor del id es el que traigo en la consulta general, lo que quiero saber es la cantidad de veces que está ese id consultado en la tabla

Answer (score 1):

Ahi lo pude resolver:

```
select id, nombre, ventas, (select count(id) from nombre_tabla as t1 where pago='ok' and t1.id=t2.id) as anteriores from nombre_tabla as t2 where pago='ok'
```

Debí poner alias a ambas tablas (aunque sean la misma) y comparar los id de cada una

Comment: Esta funciona, pero la de Steven Camargo es mucho mas rapida